# ValidForm Builder - handle submitted data

Tags: php, validation

**NVM I've figured out this by now, turns out I was just completly retarded...**

I've been looking at the tutorials for this ValidForm Builder. I can't seem to find anywhere where it explains how to get just the pure submitted data. I don't care if the data is stored in arrays, as these can be manipulated. The only thing i can see, is that when a form is submitted it stores the data in someform of email friendly-html code.

```
$objForm = new ValidForm("newsletterForm", "");
$objForm->addField("name", "Your name", VFORM_STRING, 
    array(
        "maxLength" => 255, 
        "required" => TRUE
     ), 
array(
    "maxLength" => "Your input is too long. A maximum of %s characters is OK.", 
    "required" => "This field is required.", 
    "type" => "Enter only letters and spaces."
     )
);
 $objForm->addField("email", "Email address", VFORM_EMAIL, 
    array(
         "maxLength" => 255, 
         "required" => TRUE
     ), 
     array(
        "maxLength" => "Your input is too long. A maximum of %s characters is OK.", 
        "required" => "This field is required.", 
        "type" => "Use the format name@domain.com"
     ), array(
         "tip" => "name@domain.com"
    )
);

 $objForm->setMainAlert("One or more errors occurred. Check the marked fields and try    again.");
$objForm->setSubmitLabel("Send");

$strOutput = "";

if ($objForm->isSubmitted() && $objForm->isValid()) {
    //Do something php here if the form is sumbitted correct
    //*** Set the output to a friendly thank you note.
    $strOutput = "Thank you for your interest.";
    } else {
    //*** The form has not been submitted or is not valid.
    $strOutput = $objForm->toHtml();
 }
```

Basically I just need the raw data so I can store it into my database...

Comment: Nvm I'm just completly retarded! 

I figured out how to do this. My brain just had to buffer, lol!

Comment: Either post your own answer here or mark an answer if your question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the developers of ValidForm Builder. Let me help you out on this one.

Inside the isSubmitted && isValid statement, you can do this:

```
if ($objForm->isSubmitted() && $objForm->isValid()) {

    // You can store it in a local variable or just use the result of getValue() directly.
    $strEmail = $objForm->getValidField("email")->getValue();

}
```

Indeed, if you want to post the values directly as an e-mail directly, we've got some built in support for that as well (since most website forms are contact forms, we figured that would be handy):

```
if ($objForm->isSubmitted() && $objForm->isValid()) {

    // Use strEmailBody as the HTML content of your e-mail message or wrap some fancy
    // styling around it before sending.
    $strEmailBody = $objForm->valuesAsHtml();

}
```

Furthermore, it's not recommended to save 'raw' posted data in your database. This is one of the main purposes of ValidForm Builder: to prevent SQL injection by validating user input. Since we all know: user input is evil.